# What does "sign it voluntarily as my own free act" mean?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, pennsylvania, language

At the very end of a company's severance agreement (for laid-off employees), just before the signature box, the agreement reads (emphasis mine):

> I HAVE CAREFULLY READ THE FOREGOING RELEASE, FULLY UNDERSTAND ITS
> MEANING AND CONSEQUENCES, AND **SIGN IT VOLUNTARILY AS MY OWN FREE
> ACT**.

Given that an employee isn't voluntarily laid off (i.e. being faced with this agreement in the first place isn't a voluntary act), and that an employee *must* sign essentially under the threat of not receiving severance pay and benefits if they don't (i.e. they "voluntarily" sign it in the same way they "voluntarily" don't drive head first into oncoming traffic), this seems like a curious thing to state: It does not seem that the employee is *really* voluntarily signing it under their own free act. They kind of have to sign it, or they're hosed.

My questions are:

1. What does this language protect the company against?
2. What employee rights does this forfeit if the employee signs?

That is, what purpose does this language serve?

The reason I am wondering is: There are many contracts *without* this language, are those contracts therefore not protected against claims that signing them was forced? For the implication that "if you don't like it don't sign it", isn't that true of any contract even without this sentence? If the company didn't put this language in, it seems like it would be similar to any other typical contract that also does not have this language, so if it was a generally required protection I would expect to see it all the time. What could make this agreement different as to require that statement?

Comment: It means "[circumstances force me to sign this document, unread, as-is](https://youtu.be/seQgP2qyMk4)."

Comment: AFAIK this is typically there when the signature *is* involuntary and they want to lie to the court and say it wasn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does "sign it voluntarily as my own free act" mean? What does this language protect the company against?

It secures the signer's admission that he is not being subjected to wrongful termination. It is a form of settlement with which the company could refute claims of wrongful termination, breach of contract, or similar.

> What employee rights does this forfeit if the employee signs?

It depends on the jurisdiction, since each legislation might provide different remedies for labor disputes; whether employment is at-will vs. of specific duration, or termination is for [good] cause; and other terms of the employment contract regarding the method of termination.

> are those contracts therefore not protected against claims that signing them was forced?

That language is not really necessary. It just tends to make it easier for the employer to refute claims that employee might subsequently file in court or --if mandatory-- for quasi-judicial proceedings.

Comment: Usually, what an employee is forfeiting is unemployment insurance benefits.

Answer (score 11):

The "Severance Agreement" is a contract between the company and you.  It spells out what the company will do and probably what they expect you to do going forward.

Simple enough.

The statement you referenced merely says that you are not being forced to sign the agreement.  That's all.

You don't, presumably, have the option of remaining employed at this company but you DO NOT have to sign this agreement.  But if you don't, it's likely that any benefits being promised in the agreement will not be delivered to you.

So specifically in answer to your questions:

1. It protects them against a claim that they somehow forced you to sign the agreement.
2. Likely anything that the agreement says the company will do such as pay you a certain amount of money and the like.

Bottom line is that if you don't like the agreement, don't sign it.  If you want the benefits they are promising in the agreement, then sign it and move on.

Comment: Thanks. For #1: There are many contracts *without* this language, are those contracts therefore *not* protected against claims that signing them was forced? And for the bottom line: Isn't that true of any contract? In other words, if the company *didn't* put this language in, it seems like it would be similar to any other typical contract that also does not have this language, i.e. still without problems? I've seen a lot of contracts (*seen*, not *understood*, heh), what makes *this* one different as to require that statement?

Comment: For whatever reason their attorneys wanted that language.  Ask them if you want to know why.  Does this mean that you could not later sue them claiming coercion?  Of course not but then you'd certainly be asked "why then did you sign this agreement that says 'voluntarily'?

Comment: @jwh20 “I sign this contract without coercion” is a lot like “this statement is true”.

Comment: @Sneftel I believe the term is "tautology."

Comment: @jwh20 `why then did you sign this agreement that says 'voluntarily'?` To which the answer would be "what part of 'coercion' do you not understand?" I don't see how such language could have any weight whatsoever.

Comment: I'm not arguing for or against this clause.  Someone, however, though it beneficial to them to include it.

Comment: @Aetol Also, it seems like succumbing to coercion is still a free act, philosophically, anyways, heh... right? My only theory is that maybe they had a run-in with an employee in the past and added it for some reason to try to avoid it happening again. Possibly related, this particular agreement also gives the signer a period of 7 days after signing to revoke their signature. I have their legal department's contact info, I'll ask on Monday.

Comment: It's a large-ish international corporation, too; maybe it's a protection that's got more relevance to some other jurisdiction outside the US? I know they at least have large branches in the UK and UAE, and I'm sure elsewhere.

Comment: @JasonC that agreement was surely drawn up under US law by a US lawyer, and they surely use different agreements in other countries drawn up under the laws of those countries by lawyers in those countries. "My only theory is that maybe they had a run-in with an employee in the past and added it for some reason to try to avoid it happening again": or some other company did, and they read about the court case that resulted.

Comment: @Aetol "I don't see how such language could have any weight whatsoever": one thing lawyers learn to do is to say everything explicitly even if it ought to be obvious or, like a claim of non-coersion, is logically meaningless.  Someone who is coerced to sign a contract is going to have a harder time establishing the coercion in court if the contract says that there was no coercion, at least on average.  There's always a chance that the judge or jury decides that the contract language is decisive or that self-serving claims of coercion lack credibility.

Answer (score -2):

"what purpose does this language serve?"

One way of looking at this is it allows the employer to place the employee in a [Double Bind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bind) situation.

The first injunction of the Double Bind is often implied but not stated.

> Sign this severance agreement, or you will be punished. (not receiving severance pay and benefits)
> Do not sign this severance agreement, because then we will use it against you. (implying you chose to take our offer freely)

The second injunction of the Double Bind is then written in almost classic form.

> You must sign this severance agreement, but only because you want to.

Double binds are often utilized as a form of control without open coercion, because the use of confusion makes them difficult to respond to and to resist.  The person responding will automatically be wrong, no matter how they respond, and in this case, cannot opt-out, because as stated in the question, "being faced with this agreement in the first place isn't a voluntary act."